# Class method decorator with arguments

Tags: python, decorator

So, here's a method:

```py
def evaluate(self): return self.left ** self.right
```

And it can raise an `OverflowError` if the result is too big.
To fix it (or convert to a different exception), you can e.g. decorate it:

```py
def overflow_adapter(method):
    def wrapper(self):
        try:
            return method(self)
        except OverflowError:
            raise ValueError("Result is too big!")
    return wrapper


@overflow_adapter
def evaluate(self): return self.left ** self.right
```

What I want to achieve is to be able to decorate methods with a specific decorator, which converts multiple different exceptions to one specific:

```py
@exception_adapter(aware=[OverflowError,], response=ValueError("Result is too big!"))
def evaluate(self): return self.left ** self.right
```

I would write something like this (... are places I don't know how to complete:

```py
def exception_adapter(...):
    def wrapper(...):
        try:
            return method(self)
        except BaseException as e:
            if e in aware: raise response
    return wrapper
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Good explainer on decorators with parameters here: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845#decorator-functions-with-decorator-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from functools import wraps


def exception_adapter(
    aware: tuple[type[BaseException]],
    response: BaseException,
):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except aware as e:
                raise response from e

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@exception_adapter(
    aware=(OverflowError,),
    response=ValueError("Result is too big!"),
)
def evaluate(a, b):
    if a > 3:
        raise OverflowError("foo")
    return a ** b


print(evaluate(2, 7))
print(evaluate(5, 7))
```

The output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_625.py", line 9, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "scratch_625.py", line 21, in evaluate
    raise OverflowError("foo")
OverflowError: foo

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scratch_625.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(evaluate(5, 7))
  File "scratch_625.py", line 11, in wrapper
    raise response from e
ValueError: Result is too big!
```